Нужна ли запятая в данной разговорной фразе?
Но(?) что это я?
(Человек говорит, спохватившись.)

• Но что это я?
Значение: Но что я делаю? Но что я говорю?
• Да, действительно, можно поставить многоточие после "но".
А можно и тире (для усиления оттенка неожиданности): Но — что это я?
• Спохватиться (разг.) — внезапно вспомнить о чём-либо забытом, обнаружить какое-либо упущение, допущенную оплошность, промах.
В таком "спохватывающемся" состоянии человек обычно говорит очень быстро — именно поэтому в данной конструкции чаще всего нет никаких знаков.
• Примеры
Мне уж и не желается как-то ничего, и не снится надежд никаких, и вял я сделался, а ведь если жить, так надо работать, хоть для пропитания. Но что это я, чем занимаю Вас: ропотом? Прочь эти мрачные мысли, передо мной теперь Вы, с ясным взглядом и дружеской улыбкой (из письма И. А. Гончарова Ю. Д. Ефремовой);
Только вот у него ничего не вызнаешь. Но что это я? Есть ведь одно существо, которое способно понять меня (Алексей Иванов. Географ глобус пропил);
Видимо, это был действительно хороший человек, раз столько людей его уважали и, как и я, готовы на все ради мести. Но что это я? Опять, как все, бегу непонятно куда и зачем (В. Лев. От мудреца до невежды).
Но что это я? Сам дурак (А. Беляков. Письма к дочери).

Многоточие вполне справляется с этой функцией. Тире в данном случае используется для логического выделения. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=90

Здесь не запятая нужна, а многоточие.
Внутри предложения многоточие ставится в следующих случаях (обычно в художественных текстах):
а) для передачи прерывистого характера речи:
— Ты талантливый... А талант, это... не как у всех... (Б. Паст.); — Елена... ты не бойся... иди туда... (Булг.);
Я не смею назвать себя писательницей, но... все-таки и моя капля меда есть в улье... Я напечатала разновременно три детских рассказа, — вы не читали, конечно... много переводила и... и мой покойный брат работал в «Деле» (Ч.);
Жить бы да жить вам, молодым... а вас... как этих... угорелых по свету носит, места себе не можете найти (Шукш.);
б) для передачи затрудненности речи:
— Дала бы девке образование закончить хоре... хоре... — не с первого раза, с раскачки берет мудреное слово дед, — хо-ре-ог-ра-фи-чес-кое (Аст.).
Многоточие внутри предложения может указывать на несовместимость значений слов, на необычность, алогичность их сочетания: Клад... под общежитием (газ.); Аэростат... в сумочке (газ.); Награда... до старта (газ.); Купаются... на берегу (газ.).
См.: Полный академический справочник.
